# How do I convert two floats of latitude and longitude into Google Maps latlng?

Tags: python, google-maps, latitude-longitude, compass-geolocation

I have the latitude and longitude of places in a dataframe. I am looking to get the zip code using Google Maps API.  Now I am trying to write a loop to do this and it won't work. The problem is the gmaps variable `latlng` How do I get two floats that are my variables into one variable that is `latlng`?

I have successfully done this went I "hardcode" in the coordinates.

```
for index, row in bike_df.iterrows():

    lat = row["Starting Station Latitude"]
    long = row["Starting Station Longitude"]


    target_url = ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'
              'latlng=34.052898,-118.241562&key={0}').format(gkey)
    response = requests.get(target_url).json()

    try:
        print(response['results'][0]['address_components'][7]['long_name'])
    except:
        print(f"Could not {index} find zip")
```

```
for index, row in bike_df.iterrows():

    lat = row["Starting Station Latitude"]
    long = row["Starting Station Longitude"]


    target_url = ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'
              'latlng=lat,long&key={0}').format(gkey)
    response = requests.get(target_url).json()

    try:
        print(response['results'][0]['address_components'][7] . 
         ['long_name'])
    except:
        print(f"Could not {index} find zip")
```

It just runs and runs without any output.

Answer (score 0):

Your `lat` and `long` variables aren't being inserted in the `target_url` string. You'll need to do something like:

```
target_url = ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'
          'latlng={lat},{long}&key={gkey}').format(lat=lat,long=long,gkey=gkey)
```

Comment: This works. Thank you! I thought it had to be one variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use, like you did with gkey, concatate your variable. You can do it in several way.

For example:

```
target_url = ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'
          'latlng='+str(lat)+','+str(long)+'&key={0}').format(gkey)
```

or somehting like

```
target_url = ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={0},{1}&key={2}').format(lat, long, gkey)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'lat':[34.052898,34.052898,34.052898],
     'long':[-118.241562,-118.241562,-118.241562]})

df

for index, row in df.iterrows():

    latlng = lat + long

    print(latlng)
```

> [34.052898, -118.241562]
>   [34.052898, -118.241562]
>   [34.052898, -118.241562]

```
lat = row["Starting Station Latitude"]
    long = row["Starting Station Longitude"]


    target_url = ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'
              'latlng=lat,long&key={0}').format(gkey)
    response = requests.get(target_url).json()

    try:
        print(response['results'][0]['address_components'][7] . 
         ['long_name'])
    except:
        print(f"Could not {index} find zip")
```